# Maple, converting from polar to cartesian expression?

Tags: maple

In Maple I have a polar expression

[image]

and I need to convert it to a Cartesian expression. Though the `convert` function of Maple doesn't seem to have an option for this.

I currently have a by-hand conversion:

[image]

Though there has to be a proper automatic version, isn't there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general mechansisms are,

```
G:=a+b*I;

                            G := a + I b

H:=convert(G,polar);

              H := polar(|a + I b|, argument(a + I b))

evalc(H);

                               a + I b
```

So, for your example with given operator specifying the modulus,

```
r := (theta,a,epsilon) -> a*(1-epsilon^2)/(1+epsilon*cos(theta)):

evalc( polar( r(theta,a,epsilon), theta ) );

      /        2    \                  /        2    \           
    a \-epsilon  + 1/ cos(theta)   I a \-epsilon  + 1/ sin(theta)
    ---------------------------- + ------------------------------
       1 + epsilon cos(theta)          1 + epsilon cos(theta)
```